# Weighted samples and accurate sample size in R

Tags: sample-size, weighted-sampling

I'm using IPUMS CPS data for my analysis of various subgroups. IPUMS CPS is a weighted data set. My initial sample with 33 variables has 152,732 observations. My subgroups have gotten significantly smaller as I control for more characteristics, gender, race/ethnicity, age, etc., which is what I assumed would happen, but I did not think the sample size/observations would get quite this small.

See my R code below.

```
# American Indian/Aleut/Eskimo Earning for Women (62 observations)

AIf_earnings <- bias %>% filter(EARNWEEK != 0, EARNWEEK < 9999.99, 
                                SEX == 2, RACE == 300, AGE >= 25)
weightedMedian(AIf_earnings $EARNWEEK, AIf_earnings$ASECWT)
```

It seems like [Kish sample size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_effect#Effective_sample_size) is what is most often used. Specifically, ["srvyr" and "survey"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/srvyr/vignettes/srvyr-vs-survey.html) R package are most commonly used for summary statistics given weighted data sets.

However, despite my research, I'm still not sure how I should compute the sample size with the weighted survey data, and I fear given my tiny sample sizes and the figures I have computed I likely will be unable to report my findings. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://international.ipums.org/international/variance_estimation.shtml